# Why does if then return break end not work in Lua inside for loop

Tags: lua

I have the following function which checks if the given parameter is found as a key in a key-value table. If that is the case it should return `true` and break out of the loop. If nothing is found then do nothing.

```
function checkId(id)
  for k,v in pairs(info) do
    if id == tostring(k) then
      return true
      break -- break out of loop. mission accomplished.
    end
  end
end
```

I get an

> 'end' expected (to close 'do' at line 192) near 'break'

when I try to run this script. What am I missing?

Comment: You can't `return` **and** `break`. `return` exits the function. In lua 5.1 `return` also has to be the last statement in a block.

Comment: What do you suggest to do in this case? I need this function to return something if the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: ha how stupid of me. thank you, it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logically you can't `return` **and** `break` like that.

`return` exits the function immediately (so you don't need the `break`).

That specific error is because in lua `return` has to be the last statement in a block.

Comment: `return` has to be the last statement in a block in every recent Lua version. It's `break` that had this restriction lifted because it can't take arguments anyway.

Comment: @siffiejoe Huh, indeed. I wonder what I was thinking about wrt `return` then. Thanks.